# Append Dropdown options via function not appending

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working to attempt to append values to a dropdown via a function and nothing is being appended. The only thing showing is the "Dropdown Options". I even attempted to add a  tag that would get updated when the function was called and that's not getting updated either so I can't tell if my function is being properly called.

I've currently just got it as

```
<select id="team" onchange="getTeams()">
    <option>Dropdown Items</option>
</select>

let select = document.getElementById("team");
let elmnts = ["HTML", "CSS", "JS"];

function getTeams(){
    for(let i = 0; i < elmnts.length; i++){
       let optn = elmnts[i];
       let el = document.createElement("option");
       el.textContent = optn;
       el.value = optn;
       select.appendChild(el);
    }
}
```

Not, I only took the snippets of the code, the function and variables are in the script portion and the html in the html section.

Comment: Do you really have just one pre-existing option, as in the shown code? Then this can't work - that option is considered selected by default, and since you did not give the user any _other_ option to switch to, the `change` event won't fire to begin with. (And once you fixed that issue, this code would of course keep on appending the same options over and over again, every time you change the selection.)

Comment: Yes, the only option in the select is Dropdown Option. I got the issue of it appending the options to the list by moving the variables inside the function, but like you mentioned it's infinitely adding the same options to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change onchange() to onfocus() and check the length of your select

```js
let initialLength = document.getElementById("team").length

function getTeams(){
    let select = document.getElementById("team");    
    let elmnts = ["HTML", "CSS", "JS"];
    if (select.length == initialLength){
       for(let i = 0; i < elmnts.length; i++){
          let optn = elmnts[i];
          let el = document.createElement("option");
          el.textContent = optn;
          el.value = optn;
          select.appendChild(el);
       }
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="team" onfocus="getTeams()">    
    <option>Dropdown Items</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

lots of ways to do this.  here's one approach to get you started

```js
function getTeams(){
   
    if (document.getElementById("sport").value == "soccer"){
        document.getElementById("soccer").style.display = 'block'
        document.getElementById("football").style.display = 'none'
    }else{
        document.getElementById("football").style.display = 'block'
        document.getElementById("soccer").style.display = 'none'
    }   
}
```

```css
#football{
display:none;
}

select{
   width:136px;
   text-align:center;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sport"  onchange="getTeams()">
    <option>choose one</option>
    <option value="soccer" selected>Soccer</option>
    <option value="football" check>Football</option>
</select>


<br>

<select id="soccer" >    
    <option>Manchester United</option>
    <option>Arsenal</option>
    <option>Milan</option>
</select>

<select id="football" >    
    <option>Steelers</option>
    <option>Giants</option>
    <option>Rams</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm looking more towards keeping the variable inside the function instead of using the option tag, that way I can potentially add more versatility to it in the future. That way if I want to add more conditions or api calls that's a possibility.

Comment: I've updated the snippet.  Everything is now inside the function.